# React Native Splash Screen on Android 12

Tags: android, react-native, splash-screen, android-12

I am using `react-native-splash-screen` library for making my custom splash screen in the app from an image on both iOS and Android.

However, Google introduced the new splash screens approach in Android 12, which causes problems such as splash screen duplicating, lack of customisation and the need to migrate to this new implementation removing the old screen.

I like my old splash screen and don't want to remove it, moreover I've seen that the Instagram app (which is on React Native also) seems to use not Android 12 native splash, but the custom one, so there definitely should be a way to achieve this.

So how can I leave my custom implementation accurately the same without any problems with performance and with the ability to use the full screen image like it was earlier?

Answer (score 11):

It was quite easy indeed to configure my old implementation for Android 12 and leave it with the same behavior:
First, change you `app/build.gradle` file with the following:

```
android {
   compileSdkVersion 31
   ...
}
dependencies {
   ...
   implementation 'androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.0-beta01'
}
```

Then, add this style to your styles:

```xml
<style name="Theme.App.Starting" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/AppTheme</item> // or other theme you want to use
</style>
```

In the `AndroidManifest.xml` change the theme of your main activity:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.App.Starting"
```

The last step: in the `MainActivity.java` change:

```java
@Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    androidx.core.splashscreen.SplashScreen.installSplashScreen(this); // native splash screen which will be skipped
    org.devio.rn.splashscreen.SplashScreen.show(this, true); // custom splash screen from react-native-splash-screen library
    super.onCreate(null);
  }
```

This will keep your custom splash screen implementation and, which is more important, the custom design ability.
I made so in my app and everything works perfect, my app is opening immediately and right away with the custom image splash.

P.S. I have an opinion that Instagram uses the same hack, as the Instagram app (which is in React Native and probably uses this library) opens with its custom splash on Android 12, not the native one.

Comment: Duplicate issue is resolved. But there is a small delay to open the app after tapping on Icon. Have you ever noticed that?

Comment: Did not notice any delays the last time I tested, but it could change

Comment: usual behaviour is --> App is opened as soon as I tap on app icon then default Android 12 splash screen is shown followed by custom splash screen. But when I applied your solution --> it takes some time(less than a second) top open the app and custom splash screen is shown. I presume, this delay is to prevent the default Android 12 splash screen and then to open the custom splash screen. Is there any way to prevent this delay?

Comment: Setting android:windowIsTranslucent to true causes all kinds of unwanted side effects, such as crashes when setting the orientation to portrait, and the app being displayed as the desktop when swiping up from the bottom of the screen (i.e. the overview used to browse open apps and hard closing them)

Answer (score 1):

For who uses expo-splash-screen and updated version of [Anton's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72003648/14104131)

- android/app/build.gradle

```
    android {
       compileSdkVersion 31
       ...
    }
    dependencies {
       ...
       implementation 'androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.0-beta02'
    }
```

- android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml

```xml
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
      ...
      <style name="Theme.App.Starting" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/AppTheme</item>
      </style>
    </resources>
```

- android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

```
  <application>
    ...
    <activity android:theme="@style/Theme.App.Starting">
     ...
    </activity>
   
  </application>
```

- android/app/src/main/java/.../MainActivity.java

```java
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Set the theme to AppTheme BEFORE onCreate to support 
    // coloring the background, status bar, and navigation bar.
    // This is required for expo-splash-screen.
    androidx.core.splashscreen.SplashScreen.installSplashScreen(this);
    setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
    super.onCreate(null);
  }
```

But it may looks like there is a delay while app opening on Android 12+. This is happening because the native splash screen is rendering before the app's splash screen but its invisible. The workaround for this you can use the both splash screen with making them same until the expo-splash-screen is fixed. You can check updates from [this issue](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/20244)

Answer (score 0):

This problem is due to default splash screen in Android 12.
To resolve it you can replace the default splash screen with a transparent screen by adding this code:

true

Go to res/values/styles.xml and edit the file like this.

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:editTextBackground">@drawable/rn_edit_text_material</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item> // add this line
</style>
```

Source: https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen/issues/613#issuecomment-1538231552

Comment: If android:windowIsTranslucent = true it will make deplay when tapping on Icon to open the app. I hope you know it.